# Lyapunov stability f.o.differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-theory

I have first order differential equation:
$$y'-\frac{y}{x}+3y^2x=0$$
I found a general solution:
$$y=\frac{x}{x^3+C_1}$$
$$C_1=\frac{x-x^3y}{y}$$
How can I check the stability of the solutions $y(1)=0$ and $y(1)=1$ to the following differential equation using the Lyapunov stability definition?

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to know what is $x'$?

Comment: @Xichu I think so

Comment: How do you define the stability of a solution? What problems do you have applying this? // With $u=x^2y$ one gets $u'=x^2y'+2xy=3xy-3y^2x^3=\frac3x u(1-u)$. Perhaps the stability of the stationary solutions $u=0$ and $u=1$ is easier to analyze?